# Convergence of $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\chi(n) \Lambda(n)}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to prove convergence of certain series related to non-principal Dirichlet series. In the proof, I want to use the following fact:
$$ \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} \tag{1} $$
converges as $x\to\infty$. Here $\chi$ is some non-principal character (say, mod $k$) and $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function.

The only proof of convergence of (1) I know follows from Lemmas 7.3-7.8 in Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. The proof feels a little bit long-winded for me (maybe because I do not understand it well), so here is my question:

> How would one directly prove that (1) converges ?

Comment: I believe that this is equivalent to the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions, so there will not be an easier way to prove the convergence to $0$.

Comment: @EricNaslund: Good point. I suspect that the convergence of the series above is an easier task than showing that it, in fact, converges to $0$. (In fact, Apostol proves the convergence of (1) at least 3 chapters before he proves the Prime Number Theorem, so this somehow doesn't feel as hard as PNT).

Comment: Apostol doesn't prove the convergence of $(1)$ in chapter 7 (I think not at all in the book). He proves that $(1)$ is bounded (for a non-principal character). That is what is needed there. As Eric notes, convergence of $(1)$ [for all non-principal characters (modulo $k$)] is roughly equivalent to the PNT in arithmetic progressions (with difference $k$). Also, it's roughly equivalent to the nonvanishing of $L(s,\chi)$ on the whole line $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks a lot for your comment. It has been such a long time since I have thought about this problem, but please feel free to put your comment into the answer box below, so we can remove this question from "unanswered" queue.

Comment: I'd rather write something more comprehensive. I have to think a bit about what to write, I'll probably do it tomorrow. After six years, one day more or two don't matter all that much.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you so much! And yes, it doesn't make any difference :) Please take your time.

Comment: Sorry, I got sucked into reading yesterday, and then it was too late for writing. But I managed today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence of $(1)$ lies relatively deep, and Apostol only proves the boundedness, not convergence, since that is what is needed for the version of Dirichlet's theorem proved in Apostol's book (the version and proof are due to Shapiro). The boundedness of $(1)$ is equivalent to the non-vanishing of $L(1,\chi)$. This is fairly easy to see if one concentrates on just that. Following Mertens (but using modern notation), we have
\begin{align}
-L'(1,\chi) + O\biggl(\frac{\log x}{x}\biggr)
&= \sum_{k \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(k)\log k}{k} \\
&= \sum_{k \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(k)}{k}\sum_{n \mid k} \Lambda(n) \\
&= \sum_{k \leqslant x} \sum_{n\cdot m = k} \frac{\chi(m)}{m}\cdot \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} \\
&= \sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} \sum_{m \leqslant x/n} \frac{\chi(m)}{m} \\
&= \sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n}\biggl(L(1,\chi) + O\biggl(\frac{n}{x}\biggr)\biggr) \\
&= L(1,\chi)\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} + O\biggl(\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leqslant x} \lvert \chi(n)\Lambda(n)\rvert\biggr) \\
&= L(1,\chi)\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} + O(1)\,.
\end{align}
The last step uses Chebyshev's bound $\psi(x) = O(x)$. Thus, if $L(1,\chi) \neq 0$ we can divide by that and rearrange to see that $(1)$ is bounded. For the converse direction we note that boundedness of $(1)$ implies boundedness of
$$\sum_{p \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(p)\log p}{p} \tag{2}$$
since
$$\Biggl\lvert\sum_{\substack{p^m \leqslant x \\ m \geqslant 2}} \frac{\chi(p^m)\log p}{p^m}\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{\substack{p^m \leqslant x \\ m \geqslant 2}} \frac{\log p}{p^m} < \sum_{\substack{p^m \\ m \geqslant 2}} \frac{\log p}{p^m} = \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p(p-1)} < +\infty\,,$$
and by Dirichlet's test boundedness of $(2)$ implies the convergence of
$$\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}\,.$$
This in turn implies the convergence of
$$\sum_p \log \biggl(1 - \frac{\chi(p)}{p}\biggr)$$
and hence
$$L(1,\chi) = \exp \bigl(-\sum_p \log \biggl(1 - \frac{\chi(p)}{p}\biggr)\biggr) \neq 0\,.$$

The convergence of $(1)$ is equivalent to the non-vanishing of $L(s,\chi)$ on the whole line $\sigma = \operatorname{Re} s = 1$, just like the convergence of
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$$
is equivalent to the non-vanishing of $\zeta(s)$ on that line, and we can prove it in an analogous manner.

First we note for the implication "$(1)$ converges $\implies L(s,\chi) \neq 0$ for $\sigma = 1$" that generally the convergence of a Dirichlet series at a point $s_0 = \sigma_0 + i t_0$ implies that the function $F(s)$ represented by the Dirichlet series cannot have a pole on the line $\sigma = \sigma_0$, since for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we then have ([Proposition 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence))
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \; \varepsilon \cdot F(\sigma_0 + \varepsilon + it) = 0\,.$$
But a zero of $L(s,\chi)$ is a pole of $-\frac{L'(s,\chi)}{L(s,\chi)}$.

For the other direction, that the absence of zeros on $\sigma = 1$ implies convergence of $(1)$, one can use many of the same techniques used to prove the prime number theorem. For example Newman's Tauberian theorem tells us (since we already know $(1)$ is bounded) that
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \biggl(\frac{L'(1,\chi)}{L(1,\chi)} + \sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n}\biggr)\,dx$$
exists as an improper integral. Since the sum changes slowly, it follows that the parenthesis in the integral must converge to $0$.

The proof that $L(s,\chi)$ has no zeros on $\sigma = 1$ can be modelled on Mertens's proof for the $\zeta$-function. If $\chi$ is a non-real character, or $t \neq 0$, then
$$L(\sigma,\chi_0)^3 \cdot \lvert L(\sigma + it, \chi)\rvert^4 \cdot \lvert L(\sigma + 2it, \chi^2)\rvert \geqslant 1 \tag{3}$$
for all $\sigma > 1$. Since $L(s,\chi_0)$ has a *simple* pole at $1$, this is only compatible with $L(1 + it, \chi) = 0$ if $L(s,\chi^2)$ has a pole at $1 + 2it$. But the only pole of all the $L$-functions is the pole of $L(s,\chi_0)$ at $1$, so that would mean $\chi^2 = \chi_0$, i.e. $\chi$ real, and $t = 0$. But this is the case excluded from consideration. (We see once again that the case of $L(1,\chi)$ for real characters is special; all other cases can be done at once with a single argument.)

One can use $(3)$ (or a similar inequality using a different cosine polynomial to obtain better estimates) and upper estimates for $\lvert L(s,\chi)\rvert$ and $\lvert L'(s,\chi)\rvert$ for $\sigma \geqslant 1 - \frac{c}{\log \lvert t\rvert}$ to obtain lower bounds for $\lvert L(s,\chi)\rvert$ in a region $\sigma \geqslant 1 - \frac{a}{(\log \lvert t\rvert)^{\alpha}}$ (the exponent $\alpha$ depends on the used cosine polynomial, for the classical Mertens polynomial $3 + 4\cos \varphi + \cos (2\varphi) = 2(1 + \cos \varphi)^2$ we have $\alpha = 9$, the "cubic" $5 + 8\cos \varphi + 4\cos (2\varphi) + \cos (3\varphi)$ gives $\alpha = 7$) and an $O\bigl(x\exp\bigl(-b(\log x)^{1/(\alpha+1)}\bigr)\bigr)$ error term in the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions.

But the convergence of $(1)$ (for all non-principal characters modulo $k$) alone already gives
$$\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ n \equiv h \pmod{k}}} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}
= \frac{1}{\varphi(k)}\log x + C_{k,h} + o(1) \tag{4}$$
and consequently
$$\psi_{k,h}(x) = \sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ n \equiv h \pmod{k}}} \Lambda(n)
= \frac{x}{\varphi(k)} + o(x)$$
and $\pi_{k,h}(x) \sim \frac{\operatorname{Li}(x)}{\varphi(k)}$ for $(h,k) = 1$, i.e. the PNT for the arithmetic progressions with difference $k$.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to write this detailed answer!

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Could you explain in detail why the improper integral
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{L'(1,\chi)}{L(1,\chi)}+\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n}\right)dx$$
exists, and how to deduce that the parenthesis in the integral must converge to $0$?       Let $\psi_\chi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\leq x}\chi(n)\Lambda(n)$. In Jameson's book(The Prime Number Theorem page 174), He used Newman's Taubian theorem proved that
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\psi_\chi(x)}{x^2}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n}=-\frac{L'(1,\chi)}{L(1,\chi)}$$.